# Связанный запрос в Sphinx

Tags: php, mysql, search, sphinx

Реализую сейчас на одном сайте поиск по каталогу с помощью sphinx, но есть одна особенность: в поиске должны принимать участие параметры фильтров (цвет, материал и прочие). Но вывод этих фильтров для выбора, должен осуществляться динамически (формирование формы, в зависимости от найденных товаров). Т.е. в форме фильтров должны появляться только те цвета, которые есть среди найденных товаров.

Например: Человек ввел в поиске "Майка зеленая" и ему, кроме результатов поиска, должен появиться фильтр, где будет только те цвета, которые стоят у найденных товаров (преимущественно зеленый).

Что есть сейчас: есть база данных с таблицей товаров (product), таблица значений фильтров (filter_value), связующая таблица (filter_product). Есть работающий, настроенный sphinx, который индексирует таблицу product. Есть работающая фильтрация и запрос в БД, который позволяет вывести динамичные фильтры для продуктов заданной категории.

Что нужно: Нужно как-то организовать связанный запрос в Sphinx. Чтобы он выделил нужные фильтры из тех товаров, которые попали в результаты поиска.

Какие примеры, исходный код нужно предоставить - предоставлю.

Answer (score 3):

То, что вы ищете в Сфинксе и Мантикоре (форк сфинкса) называется FACET. 
Идея такая: если при поиске задать facet, то помимо главного ответа с результатами поиска вернется дополнительный ответ, включающий в себя кол-во документов из найденного, сгруппированных по заданному facet'у с кол-ом документов в каждой группе (опять же все только в рамках текущего запроса. Facet'ов может быть задано несколько: цвет, размер, ценовая категория и т.п.

Вот пример:

```
mysql> select * from idx_min where match('abc') facet color;
+------+-------------+-------+
| id   | body        | color |
+------+-------------+-------+
|    1 | abc adc def | green |
|    2 | bc abc      | red   |
|    3 | abc abc abc | green |
+------+-------------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)

+-------+----------+
| color | count(*) |
+-------+----------+
| green |        2 |
| red   |        1 |
+-------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Вот дока на нашем сайте: http://docs.manticoresearch.com/latest/html/sphinxql_reference/select_syntax.html?highlight=facet#facet